# Why fetch() parameter (signal) is not documented

Tags: javascript

As far I can find, this fetch() document on MDZ

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Read all that document you can see second params, there are keys like {body:'', method:'',...} .There is no `signal` key

Then I look at the AbortSignal interface from here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal

in that AbortSignal document, fetch() got a new key in it's second parameter. `signal`

So are those two different fetch() or they forgot to document the `signal` key in fetch() API document?

Comment: I think the abort signal is still experimental and subject to change, so it’s not in the official docs...?

Answer (score 1):

You simply looked at the wrong document. Rather than looking at "Using Fetch" look at the documentation for the `fetch()` function:

This: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

Clearly shows `signal` (the last prop) is a property of the `init` object passed into `fetch()`.